# Zend_Queue свои таблицы

Tags: php, zend-framework

Необходимо передать имя таблицы для хранения Queue и Message по умолчанию таблицы 'message' и 'queue'

Делаю вызов:

```
$options = array(
                    'driverOptions' => array(
                        'host'      => $config['resources']['db']['params']['host'],
                        'username'  => $config['resources']['db']['params']['username'],
                        'password'  => $config['resources']['db']['params']['password'],
                        'dbname'    => $config['resources']['db']['params']['dbname'],
                        'type'      => $config['resources']['db']['adapter'],
                        'queueTableName' =>  $config['resources']['db']['params']['prefix'].'queue',
                    ),
                    'options' => array(
                        Zend_Db_Select::FOR_UPDATE => true  //Каскадное
                    )
                );
                $queue = new Zend_Queue('Db', $options);
```

Самый близкий вариант решения:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431620/zend-queue-database-scheme но он выдает ошибки подключения файлов.
Как прописать свои таблицы в  Zend_Queue?

Answer (score 1):

**https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431620/zend-queue-database-scheme  тут решение.**

```
$nusnesQueue = new Nusnes_Queue_QueueAdapter($options);
$queue = new Zend_Queue($nusnesQueue, $options);
```

Где **Nusnes_Queue_QueueAdapter**  код из ссылки https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431620/zend-queue-database-scheme ну + можно на 2 таблицу написать.